AWS - Lambda takes 10 seconds to start with no cold start
I have a Node Lambda that I want to run each minute at the 45th second, so I built a script to invoke it once a minute.
const command = new InvokeCommand({
  FunctionName: "BalancerNoVPC",
  InvocationType: "Event",
});

const response = await client.send(command);

log.info("Req ID: " + response.$metadata.requestId);

This works fine, the invocation response has "StatusCode": 202 and logs show the invocation resolves with the request ID when it is supposed to do it
2024-12-06T10:15:45: INFO { m: 'Invoking Lambda' }
2024-12-06T10:15:45: INFO { m: 'Req ID: 3dc0a16d-a77d-4449-a1ff-92fbab6a929e' }
2024-12-06T10:15:45: INFO { m: 'Sleeping for 59916 ms' }

However, the execution takes a very long time when no cold start is involved. The first time it was invoked, the START event in CloudWatch was logged at 09:59:46.077Z and Init Duration was reported to be 736.98ms. It later timed out 30s later and exited, which is in line with what I'm expecting. 
However, all subsequent invocation started more than 10s later than the expected.
2024-12-06T10:15:56.195Z START RequestId: 3dc0a16d-a77d-4449-a1ff-92fbab6a929e Version: $LATEST
2024-12-06T10:16:15.166Z END RequestId: 3dc0a16d-a77d-4449-a1ff-92fbab6a929e
2024-12-06T10:16:15.166Z REPORT RequestId: 3dc0a16d-a77d-4449-a1ff-92fbab6a929e Duration: 30000.00 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB  Status: timeout

Even though the START is logged at the 56th second, it still exited only ~20s later and logged a duration of 30s. So it seems like the start time for the duration is correct, but the actual execution starts more than 10s late. I am fairly sure about this because this lambda invokes other ones (which are delayed roughly 10s as well) that consistently miss the beginning of the minute (and log errors accordingly). The soft limit for concurrent executions is 1000 and I'm not anywhere close (I'm running around 21 lambdas per minute). 
I thought this could be due to asynchronous invocations, however I'm observing the same behaviour both with InvocationType: "Event" and InvocationType: "RequestResponse". Ironically the only time it executes on time is when it performs a cold start, from then on it's always late.

You tried EventBridge to invoke your lambda ?

@YoucefLAIDANI No, the code I shared above is ran on an EC2 because EventBridge cannot schedule events on a specific second as far as I know. It's just a simple JS script running on EC2 that invokes and waits in a loop.

Maybe the lambda that was stopped because of the timeout is not stopped properly? Can you try to clean up before the timeout? https://kuharan.medium.com/how-to-handle-aws-lambda-timeout-issues-24025f4714d8

@Dev4ever Thanks, added a timer to exit gracefully before timeout happens and now it seems spot on. If you want to post an answer explaining why a timeout delays future invocations, happy to accept it.

Always nice to see questions like these downvoted with no feedback at all. Encouraging people to stay on this website rather than go for AI.

As suggested in the comments, I added a timeout to exit gracefully and this eliminated the delay in subsequent executions. Cannot find any reference to how timeouts can affect future executions but apparently they do add several seconds of delay.
